# Ruby Net::FTP throws error when directory contains one or more spaces

Tags: ruby, ftp

I am attempting to crawl through my FTP site with ftp.list(parent_path)

Whenever the parent_path variable contains a space, I get the following error

```
Ftp LIST exception: Net::FTPPermError detail: 550 /Download/Dimension: The system cannot find the file specified.

Ftp LIST exception: the parent_path (if present) was : /Download/Dimension Data
```

Here is my code snippet

```
begin
  @logger.error("on #{ip} : " + ftp.system())
  entry_list = parent_path ? ftp.list("#{parent_path}") : ftp.list
rescue => detail
  retries_count += 1
  @logger.error("on #{ip} : Ftp LIST exception: " + detail.class.to_s + " detail: " + detail.to_s)
  @logger.error("on #{ip} : Ftp LIST exception: the parent_path (if present) was : " + parent_path)
```

I have tried escaping the spaces with a \ and I tried using %20, not sure what else to try...

Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions, etc, on how to get ftp.list to honor or escape the spaces is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried quotation to escape the names?

Comment: majioa: would you mind elaborating with an example pretty please? =]

Comment: I dont know where is your exception is generated but try to quote the `parent_path` var: like this: `"'#{parent_path}'"`

Comment: I tried using single quotes and double quotes without success, I have tried double escaping and quadruple escaping the space also without success. Any other ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: how do you tried to escape the path with %20?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, I am not sure what else to try, I logged in via the ftp cli client and was able to list the contents of the directory with the path wrapped in single quotes, however, the same does not work with the ruby ftp client, the ruby ftp client returns directory not found

Comment: please show your url string that is passed into the ruby ftp client

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43859/discussion-between-jeffrey-l-roberts-and-majioa)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? This problem comes up when the ftp site's OS is Windows. I turned all of my spaces to underscore. I wish there was a better solution.